# I can't connect to my SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have a 2nd computer that I've installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express on. I got it up and running with SQL Server Management Studio and created some tables and stuff.

But I want to be able to connect to it from my other PC, the one I usually work on in my home. But when I try to make a connection I  get this error:

[image]

Now, I've checked a couple of things:

- doing a `\\SERVER` in explorer from my computer works. So im guessing DNS is ok.
- I've tried to turn the firewall on the server off, connect and back on again with no luck.
- both SQL Server (`SQLEXPRESS`) and SQL Server Browser services are running (SQL Server Agent is not).
- TCP on port 1433 is turned on.

Server name: `SERVER` is a result in the dropdown there.

Comment: have u tried with windows authentication mode???

Comment: Open SQL ServerConfigurationManager and check if the service is running or not SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) state should be running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) It sounds like the instance you're trying to reach is SQL Express.  In which case the instance will be called `myserver\sqlexpress` ("SQLEXPRESS" literal; case doesn't matter).  "myserver" won't work with a "named instance"; "myserver\sqlexpress" might do the trick.

2) You *MUST* enable TCP/IP with the SQL Configuration tool (installed when you installed MSSQL and SSMS).

3) You should turn off the firewall (brute force - don't do it if you don't have to) or enable MSSQL in the firewall (MSSQL is *not* enabled by default)

'Hope that helps - please post back what you find.

PS:

Useful link:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to connect with Named Pipes or TCP/IP sockets?
Please show a screen dump of the Advanced tab in the dialog.
Maybe you can change to TCP/IP sockets if that is how you want to connect?
SQL server needs to be configured to allow Named Pipes or TCP/IP sockets.

[How to: Enable or Disable a Server Network Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191294%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

[Choosing SQL Server's Network Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266530%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Server Name in Add Connection Dialog in the following format.
`ComputerName/SQLEXPRESS`

for example:
`MYPCNAME/SQLEXPRESS` where `MYPCNAME` is computer name & `SQLEXPRESS` is MS SQL Server instance running on the computer.